# MongoDB aggreate framework - data restructure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

using, mongodb aggreate framework, how can I go from the below:

```
[
    "rec": {
        "field1" : "123",
        "field2" : "124",
        "field3" : "125"
    }
    // ... more similar records
]
```

to this:

```
[
    { 
        "field1" : "123",
        "field2" : "124",
        "field3" : "125"
    }
    // ... more similar records
]
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: do you know all the field names in advance?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, lets say I don't, or there is too many of them to list

Comment: if you don't know all the field names in advance, you can't do this. $project requires knowing the document you want to "synthesize" so-to-speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `$project` function from aggregate framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        field1:"$rec.field1",
        field2:"$rec.field2",
        field3:"$rec.field3"}
    }
])
```